# CanJS can.route.ready() version 2.1- '#!' is changed to '#!&' on clicking the link

Tags: canjs, canjs-routing

I have an application which relies on can.route to capture the #change when the user clicks on a link.
href for the link is having pattern '#!'.
Once the change is capture by the can route utility, i am seeing the hash in the browser changing to #!&.

This is causing an additional entry in browser history stack. 
Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you define your routes?
I mean like this :

can.route(':page',{page:'home});

if you dont do that you got a route like in the question

Answer (score 0):

Could not provide a fix as there is no code to see how the route is configured. 
Looks like you are adding only additional parameters to the route. To confirm, pls execute can.route.attr(); in your developer console of the browser.

If everything is configured properly, you should get something like this for the url http://localhost/example#!currentRoutePage

---> can.route.attr();
Object {route: "currentRoutePage"}

Looks in your case, url is http://localhost/example#!&view=currentRoutePage and so route is null in the object

---> can.route.attr();
Object {view: "currentRoutePage", route: ""}

If this doesn't help much, please share the url you are seeing in the browser and the route configuration for the same.